# Dealing with html forms

Tags: actions, forms, html

I want to work with html form but i cant understand the  Action method and when we need to use it.
For example found this code on w3schools:

```
<form action="action_page.php">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" value="Mickey">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

how can we use 'lastname' in other file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in file "action_page.php" Use the following code:

```
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
```

You can read the information with the following code:

```
<pre>
    <?php 
    print_r($_POST);
؟>
</pre>
```

or

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can in the `action_page.php` use the `$_POST['lastname']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `$_REQUEST['lastname'];` and you can check it like: `echo $_REQUEST['lastname'];`